# get next-to-last window index with applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm having trouble reconciling these cases.  3 and 4 are exactly the same except for the application.  Same for 5 and 6.  I also substituted safari with brave.  They seem to work the same.  textedit also seems to work like the others.  Is finder just a special case or is there something else going on?

```
# Case 1) Give tell a string, get last window index: succeeds.
tell application "finder"
    get index of last window
end tell

# Case 2) Give tell a variable, get last window index: succeeds.
set the_application to "finder"
function_a(the_application)
on function_a(the_application)
    tell application the_application
        get index of last window
    end tell
end function_a

# Case 3) Give tell a variable, get next-to-last window index for finder: fails.
# 651:656: execution error: Finder got an error: Can’t get window before Finder window id 63457. (-1728)
set the_application to "finder"
function_b(the_application)
on function_b(the_application)
    tell application the_application
        get index of window before last window
    end tell
end function_b


# Case 4) Give tell a variable, get next-to-last window index for safari: succeeds.
set the_application to "safari"
function_c(the_application)
on function_c(the_application)
    tell application the_application
        get index of window before last window
    end tell
end function_c

# Case 5) Give tell a string, get next-to-last window index: succeeds.
tell application "safari"
    get index of window before last window
end tell

# Case 6) Give tell a string, get next-to-last window index: fails.
1420:1425: execution error: Finder got an error: Can’t get window before Finder window id 63457. (-1728)
tell application "finder"
    get index of window before last window
end tell

# Case 7) Give tell a string, get next-to-last finder window index: succeeds.
tell application "finder"
    get index of finder window before last window
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any scriptable application has an **unique** AppleScript dictionary.

Of course applications can have something in common like windows and documents but the implementation of the `windows` element and the treatment of indices are individual. There is no general convention how to do that. Even properties with the same name can have different four-character-codes (the internal terminology identifier) in different applications.

For example the [NSPositionalSpecifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspositionalspecifier) must be implemented explicitly in the target application to be able to use the `before/after` syntax.

In my option the effort to write reusable scripts for multiple applications is a waste of time.

Comment: Thanks vadian.  I was getting that idea.  I think if I just assume every application has a completely different command to accomplish the exact same action, I will be ok.  I don't use that many applications, after all.  I just have a mind to try to generalize things.  Sometimes it's good, sometimes it's bad.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you the solution for the Safari as example.

Case ONE (probably, it is your case): you Safari's settings is **"open new windows as windows"**:

```
set the_application to "Safari"
function_c(the_application)

on function_c(the_application)
    run script "tell application \"" & the_application & "\"
get index of window before last window
    end tell"
end function_c
```

Case TWO (if you Safari's settings is **"open new windows as tabs"**):

```
set the_application to "Safari"
function_c(the_application)

on function_c(the_application)
    run script "tell application \"" & the_application & "\"
get index of tab before last tab of window 1
    end tell"
end function_c
```

Answer (score 1):

The same as the code above, but for the multiple applications:

```
set the_application to choose from list {"Safari", "Finder", "TextEdit"}
if the_application is false then return

set the_application to item 1 of the_application
function_c(the_application)

on function_c(the_application)
    run script "tell application \"" & the_application & "\"
get index of last window
end tell"
end function_c
```

Comment: Thanks, Robert.  That's helpful.  But if it works for some applications, and not others, I think I'm going about this incorrectly.  I'm trying to build a library of simple applescript actions, and then hopefully chain or nest them together.

Answer (score 1):

Other beautiful example:

```
return {|Safari|:function_c("Safari"), |Finder|:function_c("Finder"), |TextEdit|:function_c("TextEdit")}

on function_c(the_application)
    try
        run script "tell application \"" & the_application & "\"
get index of last window
end tell"
    on error
        return missing value
    end try
end function_c
```